# Create new record in Journey Builder gives error that activity contains field mappings to an event which does not exist on canvas

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud

We synced our Marketing Cloud with our Service cloud and today we tried to create a new object through journey builder.

However, although our mappings are correct (checked 20 times already) we get an error in Journey builder saying "Activity contains field mappings to an event which does not exist on the canvas."

We are trying to sync our MC activity data which we pulled from our data views. 
Does anyone know possible cause?

Comment: Try refreshing the page, delete the entry source and map it again and then re-configure your activity. This should solve it

Comment: Could it be that we need to have actual email send on the canvas? Tried your solution several times already.

Comment: No, it is not an obligation to have an actual email send. I've already created Journey's with Salesforce Activities only on the canvas without a problem. Did you try duplicating the Journey?

Comment: Yes, tried duplicating both journey and data extensions, mapped it from scratch again etc. Again same error.

Comment: I assume you have already linked your entry data extension in Data Designer?